# I can not make a check if the value exists in column

Tags: php, sql

*The code does nothing*

```
include 'connection.php';

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$verify = "SELECT * FROM  `contas` WHERE  `user` =  'Richard'";
$create = "INSERT INTO  `tibitos`.`contas` (`pass` ,`user`) VALUES ('$pass',  '$user');";
if($con->query($verify)){
    echo mysqli_num_rows($verify);
}else{
    echo die($con->error);
}

?>
```

*I'm trying to make the code show the number of columns that exist 'Richard', there is one but php does not print anything*

*what is the error in my code? please help me*

if I'm doing something wrong, correct me

Comment: This post does nothing. It doesn't explain what you expect. It doesn't ask a real question.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Are there any errors in your error log?

Comment: You're passing a string to `mysqli_num_rows()`.  Read the docs.

Comment: `echo die();` is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you build up a

`$con= new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_table");`

in `connection.php`

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$verify = "SELECT * FROM  `contas` WHERE  `user` =  'Richard'";
$create = "INSERT INTO  `tibitos`.`contas` (`pass` ,`user`) VALUES ('$pass',  '$user');";

// query returns mysqli result and not false
if( $result = $con->query($verify) ){

    // Assign and print out Numbers of row(s)
    echo $count = $result->num_rows;

    // Check your count and do ...
    if( $count == 0 ) {

        // insert values or whatever
        $result = $con->query($create);

    } else {}

} else {

    // on error
    exit();

}

?>
```